# How to Turn On/Off Xdebug Profiling at Runtime?

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug

I am currently using xdebug and experimenting with profiling and viewing w/ KCacheGrind. I have it set to only operate on trigger, i.e. passing `XDEBUG_PROFILE=1` via **GET**.

There is a lot of noise in the output concerning the framework I am using and would like to be able to specifically profile a chunk of my code, like a controller, rather than the entire request.

Am I able to have xdebug profiling turned off until I choose to turn it on, like in a controller, and then turn it back off when I want?

Comment: IMO this is impossible using xdebug. But you can use Xhprof (http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.xhprof-enable.php)

Comment: Hmm, interesting @Slawek, that's the one Facebook developed right? I might try that.

Comment: Yes, it works like a charm, you can even aggregate results from different requests

Comment: Can't the drill-down in kcachegrind help you figure out what is important? I have been using the trigger mode for a long time and I find it rather useful to have the whole framework included, even if just to give me a sense of perspective.

Comment: @Louis-PhilippeHuberdeau It can, but Zend Framework likes to jump all over the place and it gets difficult to figure out what is going where. Mostly because I am new to profiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I able to have xdebug profiling turned off until I choose to turn it on, like in a controller, and then turn it back off when I want?

No, you either profile the request or you won't. You can not switch it on in one function and switch it of in another within the same request.

It wouldn't make much sense for a single request somehow, because you need to metric each part of the application in relevance to the other parts.

Alternatively there is the [xhprof extension](http://php.net/xhprof).

If you need to profile data over time from within specific areas, take a look at the [Pinba PHP Extension](http://pinba.org/wiki/Manual%3aPHP_extension).