# How to track down slow code in PHP

Tags: php, performance, cakephp

I installed an open source PHP project on my Ubuntu server and got it running.  However, pages load extremely slow.  A phpinfo() page and a basic test page connecting to the mysql db all load very fast.  There are tons of include files, log files and some curl calls in this open source code.  What strategies/tools can I use to track down the source of the slowness?

Comment: Apparently someone (none-developer?) voted to close this question as "Off topic: recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource ". If there were a choice that's arguably appropriate - but there isn't, and knowing how to debug/profile code is surely very much on topic for SO.

Comment: http://systemsarchitect.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/php-benchmark.png

Comment: @symcbean how irrelevant =).

Comment: How is this related to cake, except the tag? Open source project can be anything.

Answer (score 3):

You can use xdebug and run it through the profiler. You can visualize the profiler results via webgrind.

The following tutorials and tools will be useful:

- http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler
- https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind/wiki

Answer (score 3):

You need to profile pages, that have performance problems. It can be done with php-extension [xdebug](http://xdebug.org) and [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html).

*Follow this steps:*

1. Install **php5-xdebug** package on your Ubuntu server via: `sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug`.
2. Configure **xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger** parameter. Look at [official manual](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler).
3. Install on your local computer **kcachegrind** package: `sudo apt-get install kcachegrind`.
4. Start slow page with `GET` parameter `XDEBUG_PROFILE=1`. See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077993/can-i-manualy-say-on-xdebug-profiler-to-start-profiling-in-specic-place).
5. Copy generated profile log to your local comp and open it in kcachegrind.

*Some notes:*

- After php5-xdebug package installation you'll need to restart http-server (or php-fpm daemon. Depends on installed software on your server).
- Right place for profiling procedure is a test environment, not production.

Answer (score 1):

### Install debug kit

The definitive answer is to use xdebug profiling, which gives you a great amount of information as to what's happening. There is however also [DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit).

DebugKit is a must for any CakePHP developer, and is very easy to install (it's just a plugin).

The feature most relevant to the question is the timer panel:

[image]

Knowing which part of the request is slow, will permit you to focus your attention on where the problem is.