# Wordpress on Nginx+php5-fpm+varnish+APC high CPU and memory usage

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, varnish, apc

After days of debugging and tweaking around with settings, I'm getting exhausted & unable to find a solution. Kindly guide.

I've the following server on DigitalOcean:

```
64GB Memory
8 Core processor
200GB SSD drive
```

And I'm running a single Wordpress site on it. Site gets high traffic. (2000 to 3000 concurrent realtime users) And I'm sure due to my bad settings I'm losing traffic & unable to serve pages to users. I expect the realtime users to be 5000+ but it always stays around 2000.

I constantly get OOM errors and due to which `mysql` or `php5-fpm` gets killed and the site goes down. If I tweak `php-fpm` and `nginx` I get `502` and `503` errors. Or I get `upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out)'` or `FastCGI sent in stderr: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded` error.

Now, I've tweaked the settings so that I don't get any error but the traffic has dropped to around 1500 concurrent users and it refuses to go up. So I'm sure there's something wrong in my settings.

`/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` settings:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 150
pm.start_servers = 40
pm.min_spare_servers = 30
pm.max_spare_servers = 50
pm.max_requests = 1000
```

FastCGI settings: `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

```
location ~ \.php$ {
             try_files $uri =404;
             # proxy buffers - no 502 errors!
             proxy_buffer_size               128k;
             proxy_buffers                   4 256k;
             proxy_busy_buffers_size         256k;

            fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_keep_conn off;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-fpm-www.sock;


        }
```

APC setting: `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`

```
[apc]
apc.write_lock = 1
apc.slam_defense = 0
apc.shm_size = "1024M"
```

I've noticed that `php5-fpm` processes take a lot of memory.
E.g. when I calculate the average memory per process I get:
`ps --no-headers -o "rss,cmd" -C php5-fpm | awk '{ sum+=$1 } END { printf ("%d%s\n", sum/NR/1024,"M") }'` gives me `238M` for a concurrent traffic of 1100.

Please guide me where my config is incorrect. Because I'm 100% sure my traffic is choking.

---

Additional info

Nginx config: `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
worker_processes  24;
worker_rlimit_nofile 20000;


events {
    worker_connections  40000;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}
```

But I've noticed that ulimit on the server is:

`ulimit -n` shows `1024` only. Is this related to my issue?

---

Added VCL after Daniel's response

```
# This is a basic VCL configuration file for varnish.  See the vcl(7)
# man page for details on VCL syntax and semantics.
#
# Default backend definition.  Set this to point to your content
# server.
#
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
        .connect_timeout = 600s;
        .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
        .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
        .max_connections = 800;
}


acl purge {
        "localhost";
}

sub vcl_recv {
        set req.grace = 6h;

  # Set X-Forwarded-For header for logging in nginx
  remove req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
  set    req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;


  # Remove has_js and CloudFlare/Google Analytics __* cookies.
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(_[_a-z]+|has_js)=[^;]*", "");
  # Remove a ";" prefix, if present.
  set req.http.Cookie = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");



# Either the admin pages or the login
if (req.url ~ "/wp-(login|admin|cron)") {
        # Don't cache, pass to backend
        return (pass);
}

# Remove the wp-settings-1 cookie
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

# Remove the wp-settings-time-1 cookie
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-time-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

# Remove the wp test cookie
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", "");

# Static content unique to the theme can be cached (so no user uploaded images)
# The reason I don't take the wp-content/uploads is because of cache size on bigger blogs
# that would fill up with all those files getting pushed into cache
if (req.url ~ "wp-content/themes/" && req.url ~ "\.(css|js|png|gif|jp(e)?g)") {
    unset req.http.cookie;
}

# Even if no cookies are present, I don't want my "uploads" to be cached due to their potential size
if (req.url ~ "/wp-content/uploads/") {
    return (pass);
}

# Check the cookies for wordpress-specific items
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "wordpress_" || req.http.Cookie ~ "comment_") {
        # A wordpress specific cookie has been set
    return (pass);
}



        # allow PURGE from localhost
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
                        error 405 "Not allowed.";
                }
                return (lookup);
        }


        # Force lookup if the request is a no-cache request from the client
        if (req.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache") {
                return (pass);
        }
# Try a cache-lookup
return (lookup);

}

sub vcl_fetch {
        #set obj.grace = 5m;
    set beresp.grace = 6h;

}

sub vcl_hit {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                purge;
                error 200 "Purged.";
        }
}

sub vcl_miss {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                purge;
                error 200 "Purged.";
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a floating ip set up? You could try making an image and spinning up the next tier server, then redirect traffic to the new box to test if it handles it better. If you're CPU or ram bottlenecked, you could look into more aggressive caching? Are you running PHP7 or 5.x? Are you sure you're not getting DDOS attack? Wordpress isn't the most efficient PHP app ever, but there's testing to be done! New relic set up (or any other metrics monitoring)?

Comment: Have you tried analyzing MySQL's slow log?

Comment: @Blake Thanks for the suggestions. I'm using PHP 5.5.9. I'm using Cloudflare business plan, so a DDoS attack would be mitigated.I had setup new relic earlier but the dashboard was too confusing for me to understand and find out something of value. Do you want to have a look at the Varnish VCL file if the above settings look fine?

Comment: @mike I had enabled it long time back. But there are no entries in it now. I had enabled Object caching and Database caching with W3TC plugin using APC cache.

Comment: You should install xdebug then and profile a typical request to your site to identify the bottlenecks.

Comment: @mike Thanks for the suggestion. I've installed xdebug and it gives me a lot more info in my nginx/php logs. But I'm new to this, how can I profile a request as you suggested? Any procedure to follow, any blog links, any documentation, can you guide please.

Comment: When you [have the output](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8078229/997162) file from the profiling procedure, use app like [WinCacheGrind](http://ceefour.github.io/wincachegrind/) or phpStorm if you have one to [visualize the stack trace](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ceefour/wincachegrind/gh-pages/wincachegrind-screenshot.jpg). The file in mention is stored on the server (vide `xdebug.profiler_output_dir`).

Comment: @mike thanks for the guidance. I'll try it out. In the meantime, I've installed New Relic on the server to check.

Answer (score 0):

With that traffic and this config, you're missing a lot of opportunities (and income) :). You really should get your hands on Nginx microcaching and Varnish!

Comment: Daniel, now I'm really sad. :( 
I'm using Varnish, but not nginx microcaching. Can you kindly suggest what's wrong with my config and how I can tweak them for performance.

Comment: Don't be sad :) Install Varnish, put it in port 80, and run Nginx on port 8080. Research for good Varnish VCL config for Wordpress and apply it. Then put the Varnish IP (127.0.0.1) if running on the same machine in the W3TC settings. If you did have it in the first place - looks like it wasn't working because most of the visitor requests should be hitting on Varnish and cause NO php load whatsoever

Comment: Let me share my current Varnish VCL. My hitrate avg: from `varnishstat` `0.9168 0.8600 0.8600`. Let me add it to the question. Can you check?

Comment: Sure + would be helpful to check the website in question :)

Comment: I've added the VCL file, kindly check.

Comment: How long have you been running varnishstat to get those numbers? I don't see any logic for stripping Set-Cookie from headers in the VCL. "Normally" there is "that one" plugin that would always set cookie on every page request that you have to deal with. Also have you checked your database settings? (mysqltuner)

Comment: 1. I've running it for 5 hours while noting the numbers.

2. Okay, I know less because I've picked this VCL setting off the Internet. Is there a better VCL I can use for Wordpress for high traffic? I'm looking up too. 

3. I've not checked database settings. I've never used mysqltuner. Any guidance and advice?
Will this work on Ubuntu: https://www.howtoforge.com/tuning-mysql-performance-with-mysqltuner

Comment: Just install and run it :) It will tell you what you need to adjust. Most likely you're better off upping some MySQL buffers (primarily related to innodb engine) rather than tuning php-fpm (which would be slow anyway, as long as connection to database is slow)

Comment: Okay, let me try that. But does my VCL look fine to you? Any other recommendation